# Changing property stubs for Interface refactoring

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, interface, editor

Is it possible to change the stub used to implement interfaces in Visual Studio 2008?

For instance, when I choose either
`Implement interface 'IMyInterface'`
 or
 `Explicitly implement interface 'IMyInterface'`

Instead of a number of properties that look like this:

```
    public string Comment
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I'd like my properties to use the C# 3.0 auto-implemented properties and look like this:

```
    public string Comment {get;set;}
```

I want to do this to avoid forcing this interface to be an abstract class.

I've looked through the snippets in the Visual Studio folder, but I didn't see any that would be appropriate.  I've also googled and searched SO, and found nothing.

If this isn't possible, does anyone have a macro I can steal?

Thanks.

**edit:**  I have tried editing the snippets located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring` but these changes don't change the implementation.  I've tried making the changes, then reopening Visual Studio, which doesn't work.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Install JetBrains ReSharper. It allows you to define what should be generated and is generally a great productivity booster.

Comment: +1 Morten: that looks great. I watched a few demo videos and I see it offers exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll have to see if we have a commercial license.

Comment: By 'abstract class', I mean forcing an implementation when 90% of the time I just want an auto-implemented property stub.

Comment: This doesn't work in VS2015 via ctrl + . -- the refactorings are now separate from the snippets.

See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1857694/visual-studio-2015-implement-interface-snippet-not-working for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ReSharper may be the only way for me to go about this.

I just revisited this issue and found that you can change the snippet used by Visual Studio:

You can modify the stub Visual Studio uses to implement interfaces (both implicit and explicit) by editing the file:
`Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\PropertyStub.snippet`

I’ve changed the code segment in my file to:

```
<Code Language="csharp">
    <![CDATA[ $signature$ { $GetterAccessibility$ get; $SetterAccessibility$ set;} $end$]]>
</Code>
```