# Change the Implement Interface template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates

In Visual Studio 2010, is it possible to change the default template used when implementing an interface?

I would like to change the implementation of properties from

```
public int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

to

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

so i tried to Edit PropertyStub.snippet but to no avail, it didn't change anything...

I found this question [Changing property stubs for interface refactoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608966) which says that ReSharper is the only way.

Anyone able to make this work, with example, cause the change i made did not seem to have any effects

Comment: Have a look at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring\PropertyStub.snippet* (in the Code Snippets Manager: *Refactoring\Property Stub* for language *Visual C#*). If this is the one used by Visual Studio, I wonder if there's a way to modify it on a per-user basis rather than directly.

Comment: Kzu has the answer: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-replace-default-interface-property-implementation-expansion-with-automatic-properties/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change this template. The C# IDE uses templates for the majority of it's code generation and the IDE. You can update these templates to control the code generation process. They are located in the following directory

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Refactoring

Note: The " (X86)" portion will be absent on 32 bit machines.

For this particular situation you want to change the `PropertyStub.snippet` file.

Comment: Well I Tried but it didn't work... any requirement for this to work?

Comment: @moi_meme, did you restart VS?

Comment: Yes I did, many times... I tried just adding a contant and nothing changed... do yoou have a working example?

Comment: @LuisPalacios it does not work in 2015 -- See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1857694/visual-studio-2015-implement-interface-snippet-not-working for more info.

Comment: @scaryman -- Of course not.  Why would it?  Why keep a useful feature when you can get rid of it for no good reason?

Comment: For VS19 maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45230422/7790628