# Visual Studio C# automatically add code to abstract method

Tags: c#, visual-studio

is it possible to replace the `throw new NotImplementedException();` automatically with an `this.workThread.Start()` or something else if a specific method has been overriden?

Comment: Ability to implement interface or generate a method for you is already great help (less typing, less errors). Then you can replace `throw new NotImplementedException();` with code you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make implementation of an interface produce an auto property instead of NotImplementedException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703277/how-can-i-make-implementation-of-an-interface-produce-an-auto-property-instead-o)