# Change default style of automatic implementation of interface on Visual Studio from lambda to body expression

Tags: visual-studio, lambda, interface, styles, implementation

I would like to know if there is some way to force the default style of automatic implementation of interface on Visual Studio from lambda to body expression **for all members**. As we can see in the below picture only methods are being implemented using body expressions while member variables are being implemented using lambda expressions.

[image: Automatic Implementation]

Comment: Similat question with answer here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703277/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703277/how-can-i-make-implementation-of-an-interface-produce-an-auto-property-instead-o