# Tell VS c# to generate get{} set{} instead of get=>set=> format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have an interface class that has properties that other classes implement.
When i tell Vs to implement it generates **get => ... set=>..** is there away to tell to generate **get{...} set{...}**? im using vs 22. it also happens when im overriding a property.
[image]

Sorry for my english

Comment: That is not what i wanted. what i want is tell vs to generate get{} set{} instead of get=> set=> when overriding or implementing from interface.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17703277/9363973) Q&A